# How can I see which macOS version is installed on an external disk, without booting into it?

Tags: macos, system-information

Is there a file somewhere in the System folder or in the Library that shows me which OS is installed on the disk?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can read the SystemVersion.plist on that particular volume-

```
/Volumes/<volume_name>/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
```

Answer (score 2):

If there's a valid, bootable system on it, then it will be listed in System Preferences > Startup Disk, with its version number.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I see no system info for the external disks.

Comment: @SPRBRN That's odd. See the screenshot I've added.

Comment: I see, but here it only shows the volume name.

Comment: What OS are you currently running?

Comment: Could it mean those volumes are not bootable?

Comment: @benwiggy 10.15.

Comment: @SteveChambers - volumes are bootable, but encrypted. Maybe that's the issue here?

Comment: Could be. But they are mounted, though?

Comment: Yes they are mounted

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac, you can use the `defaults read` command to get just the "ProductVersion" from the "SystemVersion.plist" file.

```bash
defaults read /Volumes/"$Your_disk_name"/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist ProductVersion
```

To read it from a non-Mac machine, just look at the content of that `System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist` file, which is a plain text XML file.

Or on Linux, you can do

```bash
grep -A1 ProductVersion "$Your_disk_mount_point"/System/Library/CoreServices/SystemVersion.plist
```